# SSH is using the wrong folder on Windows 8, how can I change it?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, windows-8

I've been trying for the past 2 days to setup my server with passwordless SSH key logins and I just finally figured out my problem.. I'm on Windows trying to SSH into my Centos 7 machine using id_rsa as my SSH key, which is in `C:\Users\Me\.ssh\id_rsa`. I had tried everything I possibly could find online until finally today I realized I could use the `-i` command to specify the key I wanted to use.. Now, the only problem is how can I set it to default?

Now that I realize it, my `.ssh` folder has had a funky directory name for a while now.. When I run the command `ssh -keygen -t rsa` and hit enter for every prompt, this is the output:

```
C:\Users\Me>ssh-keygen -t rsa
    Generating public/private rsa key pair.
    Enter file in which to save the key (//.ssh/id_rsa):
    Could not create directory '//.ssh'.
    Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
    Enter same passphrase again:
    open //.ssh/id_rsa failed: No such host or network path.
    Saving the key failed: //.ssh/id_rsa.

C:\Users\Me>
```

How can I change the location of my SSH folder? When I attempt to connect to my machine it can't find the key so it fails the login. I'd rather not have to use the `-i` command every time I need to access my server...

**EDIT:** I'm using Git for my SSH client and my OpenSSH version is `OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007`

**EDIT** Resolved my issue by adding `C:\Users\Me` to the system PATH then restarting my console window.

Comment: Could you not use putty or kitty - they just work.

Comment: @Iain That has nothing to do with it. I do use Putty, but the purpose of SSH keys is to increase security / avoid brute forcing passwords...

Comment: putty/kitty use keys and pageant too.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for though.

Comment: Can you edit your question to say what ssh client and version you're using? It's hard to guess what setting needs tweaking without it

Comment: Is the `HOME` environment variable set correctly?

Comment: @kasperd Oh my gosh, I just checked and I didn't even have it in my path - I thought I had checked that once already but I guess not.. Thanks so much!